# Homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{120}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{167}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Find all the morphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{120}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{167}$.

I've tried that:

Let $f : \mathbb{Z}_{120} \to \mathbb{Z}_{167}$ a homomorphism.
Then let $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{120}$, then $x^{120} = e$. Because $f$ it's a homomorphism we have $f(xy) = f(x)f(y), \forall x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{120}$.

But $f(x^{120}y) = f(x^{120})f(y) = f^{120}(x)f(y) = f(y)$, So $f^{120}(x) = e$.
But $ord(\mathbb{Z}_{167}) = 167$ so then $f^{167}(x) = e$.

From that we get $f^{120}(x) = f^{167}(x) = e$. Hence $120$ and $167$ are coprime, we get $f(x) = e$ so $f(x) = e$ it's the only homomorphism.

Comment: I don't think $120$ is prime.

Comment: I mean prime with $167$.

Comment: Ah, so you meant "$120$ and $167$ are *coprime*"

Comment: Yes, sorry for my english.

Comment: Yes, use *coprime* or *relatively prime.*. The answer is correct but you can easily add an addition “why” to how coprime implies $f(x)=e.$

Comment: So, it's correct my approach?

Comment: The middle step about $f(xy)$ is unnecessary. Since $x^{120}=e,$ $(f(x))^{120}=f(x^{120})=f(e)=e.$

Answer (score 3):

The image of $f$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z_{167}}$, hence the order of the image divides $167$ by Lagrange's theorem. Since $167$ is a prime number, we have $|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=1$ or $|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=167$. But obviously there are no surjective functions from a set with $120$ elements to a set with $167$ elements, so it must be $|\operatorname{Im}(f)|=1$.

Answer (score 2):

You're right.  There's no nontrivial homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_n$ to $\Bbb Z_m$ unless $\rm{gcd}(n,m)\gt1$.

This essentially follows from Lagrange, and the homomorphism property.

Answer (score 2):

The number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_m $ to $\mathbb{Z}_n $ is $\gcd(m,n) $.
Clearly, $\gcd(120,167) = 1$, so, there is only a trivial homomorphism.